# javascript - await promise stucks

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I am implementing google video person detection .

I completely followed their docs and implemented same script they provided

But my code is not passing by this line:

```
const results = await operation.promise();
```

On terminal I get :

```
A
B
C
```

and thats it. some how code is not being processed after this line: `const results = await operation.promise();`

Here is my complete code script:

```
'use strict';

function main(path = 'my-file.mp4') {
  
  // [START video_detect_person]
  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
   */
  // const gcsUri = 'GCS URI of the video to analyze, e.g. gs://my-bucket/my-video.mp4';

  // Imports the Google Cloud Video Intelligence library + Node's fs library
  const Video = require('@google-cloud/video-intelligence').v1;
  const fs = require('fs');
  // Creates a client
  const video = new Video.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient();

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
   */
  // const path = 'Local file to analyze, e.g. ./my-file.mp4';

  // Reads a local video file and converts it to base64
  const file = fs.readFileSync(path);
  const inputContent = file.toString('base64');

  async function detectPerson() {

    console.log("A");
    
    const request = {
      inputContent: inputContent,
      features: ['PERSON_DETECTION'],
      videoContext: {
        personDetectionConfig: {
          // Must set includeBoundingBoxes to true to get poses and attributes.
          includeBoundingBoxes: true,
          includePoseLandmarks: true,
          includeAttributes: true,
        },
      },
    };

    // Detects faces in a video
    // We get the first result because we only process 1 video

    console.log("B");
    const [operation] = await video.annotateVideo(request);
    
    console.log("C");
    const results = await operation.promise();

    console.log("D");

    console.log('Waiting for operation to complete...');

    // Gets annotations for video
    const personAnnotations =
      results[0].annotationResults[0].personDetectionAnnotations;

    for (const {tracks} of personAnnotations) {
      console.log('Person detected:');

      for (const {segment, timestampedObjects} of tracks) {
        console.log(
          `\tStart: ${segment.startTimeOffset.seconds}` +
            `.${(segment.startTimeOffset.nanos / 1e6).toFixed(0)}s`
        );
        console.log(
          `\tEnd: ${segment.endTimeOffset.seconds}.` +
            `${(segment.endTimeOffset.nanos / 1e6).toFixed(0)}s`
        );

        // Each segment includes timestamped objects that
        // include characteristic--e.g. clothes, posture
        // of the person detected.
        const [firstTimestampedObject] = timestampedObjects;

        // Attributes include unique pieces of clothing, poses (i.e., body
        // landmarks) of the person detected.
        for (const {name, value} of firstTimestampedObject.attributes) {
          console.log(`\tAttribute: ${name}; Value: ${value}`);
        }

        // Landmarks in person detection include body parts.
        for (const {name, point} of firstTimestampedObject.landmarks) {
          console.log(`\tLandmark: ${name}; Vertex: ${point.x}, ${point.y}`);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  detectPerson(); 
  // [END video_detect_person]
}

main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

Comment: Video annotation sounds like something that would take a long time to complete.

Comment: @jarmod Yeah thats what I was guessing too, but video size is 133MB with runtime length of 30seconds

Comment: 1. Operation is taking a long time
2. Promise got rejected that's why it's not going to the next line add inside try/catch block.

Comment: I would find out how long the annotation takes for this video using the gcloud cli (if it supports this API) or investigate how to get status from the long running operation.

Comment: @RahulSharma How can you be sure that promise got rejected?